# Create raws automatically when values created on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets in one spreadsheet. Users add new raws to the first sheet. I need to automatically create a raw in the second sheet containing the value of the first column from the raw the user created. Could you suggest the best way?

Comment: `Users add new raws` - is it possible that you do you mean _rows_? `I need to automatically create a raw in the second sheet` Do you want to physically **copy** the information from Sheet1 to Sheet2 (this requires a script), or do you want a formula that creates a dynamic link between the two sheets? `Could you suggest the best way?` This is NOT a good question; you are inviting opinions plus we don't have any further information about your spreadsheet. Please decide whether you want a script or a formula.